Is prayer with eyes closed valid?
Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatulahi wa barakyatuh. Is my prayer valid if I sometimes close my eyes while praying? I have already found a similar question on this site, but I never understood whether the prayer is valid in this case or not?

Being makruh means it is discouraged. The prayer is valid.
